# XEvents: what is the purpose of this set statement for an output parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, extended-events

I'm using XEvents to analyze queries from a Spring application to a SqlServer DB (2019). Here's the `statement` property of an `rpc_completed` event. I don't understand what the `set @p1=67` line does:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=67
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 int,@P2 bigint',N'update MyTable set Field1 = @P0, Field2 = @P1 where ID = @P2',N'0102A',123,999
select @p1
```

I first thought it set a value for `@P1` (uppercase P), but that makes no sense because a different value for P1 (123) is passed to sp_prepexec. But otherwise, `@p1` is only used as an output parameter, so why initialize it to anything? It doesn't seem to be a default value either as a similar `set` occurs in multiple events with vastly different values. Does the `set` have a purpose here?

Also, my server uses the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation. As this is case-insensitive (CI), I would have assumed that `@p1` and `@P1` reference the same variable in the `exec` statement. As this doesn't seem to be the case, is the output part a separate scope from the query part in sp_prepexec?

Comment: An `OUTPUT` parameter in T-SQL is both input and output, so the procedure can use the incoming value as well as set it when outgoing. There is as far as I can tell no point to this for `sp_prepexec` as opposed to `sp_execute` (the incoming value is ignored and not reused) but it's still legal. And yes, the `@p1` declared in the outer scope has nothing to do with the `@P1` of the statement: this is why the parameter list of the statement to be prepared is passed as a string.

Comment: In fact, the `@p1` you see here likely doesn't actually exist as a named value, but is just how the `sp_prepexec` TDS packet is translated (although only a packet trace could tell that for sure). Similar pseudo-statements are generated for reset and login, with the difference that `sp_reset_connection` doesn't even exist as an actual sproc, while `sp_prepexec` does.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so if I understand what you're saying correctly, setting the value of an output parameter _can_ be useful if the procedure makes use of it, but is nonsense here?

Comment: It appears to be unnecessary, yes. I don't actually know if `sp_prepexec` uses the input at all; a quick test shows that passing an invalid handle will give an error, but passing a handle of a statement already prepared earlier *still* generates a new handle rather than echoing the input. So it's not that `sp_prepexec` ignores the input value entirely.

Comment: @Charlieface: No, your second sentence is not true. Like I said, `OUTPUT` merely means the parameter is also available for output, *not* that it's ignored on input. `DECLARE @i INT = 42; EXEC sp_prepexec @i OUTPUT, NULL, N'SELECT 1'` will fail as the input value is still validated. Unfortunately I have little experience with explicitly prepared statements, so I don't know the exact semantics of `sp_prepexec`, and the docs are none too clear on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using an ODBC driver which uses an RPC call to [`sp_prepexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-prepexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to execute parameterized ad-hoc SQL batches. This is the equivalent of calling `sp_prepare` and `sp_execute`. These are internal stored procedures, used for executing SQL batches, and are not normally called directly from user code.

The `select @p1` is just an artifact of the fact that the first parameter of `sp_prepexec` is an `OUTPUT` parameter. Even though it is unlikely to be used again, it could in theory be passed to `sp_execute` to execute the batch a second time.

The code you are seeing is not actually what is executed. It's just a representation of the way `OUTPUT` parameters are handled in an RPC call, so that if you wanted to execute this as a SQL batch, you could do so in SSMS. The actual call is a special RPC call direct to `sp_prepexec`.

Note also that the `@p0` and `@P0` are different variables, not because of case insensitivity, but because they are in different scopes.

---

What you presumably are actually executing is

```sql
update MyTable set Field1 = @P0, Field2 = @P1 where ID = @P2
```

And you have the parameters `@P0 nvarchar(4000) = N'0102A'` `@P1 int=123` `@P2 bigint=999`

---

Note also that `sp_prepexec` and friends can be problematic for performance, because [they disable parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/sp_prepare-isnt-good-sp_executesql-performance/). If possible, find an ODBC driver that uses `sp_executesql`, which does not.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive information. The driver is an older version (9.x) of mssql-jdbc, and it does use `sp_executesql` for other queries, along with `sp_execute`. That might be an issue with the old version, or maybe there are valid reasons to use `sp_prepexec` for some specific queries...